# PhpStorm remove line wrapping for "use statements" from code formatter

Tags: phpstorm, formatter

I would like to remove the line wrapping for the use statements in a php class when I apply Code | Reformat code.

current look:

```
use
    Acme/Foo/Bar;
```

(my) desired look:

```
use Acme/Foo/Bar;
```

I've been looking at the File | Setting | Code Style | PHP but could not find it.

Another question is that is it possible to wrap logical operators but no other binary operators using the formatter. I don't expect much though..

Answer (score 0):

Think I am relying too much on the auto-formatter. Now I figured out that I can just do whatever I want (manually) by disabling most of the line wrapping options but enabling the keep line breaks option. The "use statements" formatting as mentioned in my question is because I ticked on the wrapping option under File | Setting | Code Style | PHP | Wrapping and Braces | Function declaration parameters.